# Is there a Apache Flink machine learning tutorial in Java language

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep, flinkml

I am in search of a tutorial that tells us to setup a basic apache flink machine learning. Current [available](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/libs/ml/index.html)
material is in scala language.

Answer (score 4):

Flink's ML library does not support Java because its pipelining mechanism (being able to flexibly chain multiple `Estimators` and `Transformers`) heavily depends on Scala's implicit value resolution. Theoretically, it is possible to put the operations manually together, but this is quite tedious and not recommended.

Comment: Is this still the fact, that using flinks ML library is not recommended in the java environment?

Comment: Yes it is still quite difficult to use Flink's ML library with Java due to the implicit pipeline construction.